# Select Box Running Change Function With Size Attribute

Tags: javascript, html, select, size, multi-select

I am working with select box. I use select box like as below:

```
        <select name="cars" onchange="jsFunction()">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
          </select>

  <script>
    function jsFunction(){
       console.log($(.names).val());
    }
  <script>
```

The combo is look like as below:

[image]

THis function is working when the comboboz is chenged.But i want to show all option at the same time. But i don't want to use multiple option select. So that i used size option like as below:

```
<select name="cars" size="4" onchange="jsFunction()">
       <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
       <option value="saab">Saab</option>
       <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
       <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

And then the select box look like as below:

[image]

And only only one option can selected. But my problem is not working function. When i use size attribute, and then the function is not triggered when selectbox is changed. When i remove this size, and then the function is triggered.

How can i show all option at the same time (without multiselect) without using size attribute ? Or how can i trigger this function with size attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript function shouldn't log anything at *all*, as it has a syntax error. `$(.names)` needs quotes around `names`. Also, it needs to reflect the `class` of your `<select>`.

First you need to add the class `names` to your select:

```
<select name="cars" size="4" class="names" onchange="jsFunction()">
```

And then add quotes around your jQuery DOM target:

```
console.log($('.names').val());
```

Here's the new code:

```js
function jsFunction() {
  console.log($('.names').val());
}
```

```html
<select name="cars" size="4" class="names" onchange="jsFunction()">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/q2uxc3f6/).

Hope this helps!